# Error starting the SonarQube server

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am using sonarqube with jenkins and I have an error when I start sonarqube server.

```
wrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: org.sonar.process.MessageException:Directory does not exist: lib/jdbc/h2
```

I have the last version of sonarqube(6.4). And the previous version works.

what do I need to add?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: I have only one log (sonar.log)

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: org.sonar.process.MessageException: Directory does not exist: lib/jdbc/h2
org.sonar.process.MessageException: Directory does not exist: lib/jdbc/h2
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Please post your log files (I suppose there is only one sonar.log file but if you have web.log, es.log and ce.log, post them here). Your configuration may be quite useful.

Comment: For a unknown reason, SonarQube directory seems to be incorrect. 
Did you download SonarQube from https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/ ?
Is the download complete (ie. the zip file is not corrupted) ? You can check this with the MD5 hash (https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-6.4.zip.md5) ?